# 2Checkout Sandbox Account not sending INS

Tags: payment-gateway, 2checkout

Having an issue with a sandbox account in 2checkout. `INS` is going to failure section in the sandbox account even after setting demo to `OFF`. Having this issue for past 2-3 months still not resolved. Have seen multiple posts related to such issue, but neither of the solution works or given appropriate reasons to justify it. Does 2checkout stop sending INS for sandbox accounts? INS seems to work in the live account but for sandbox account, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

2Checkout Sandbox is deprecated and no longer supported by 2Checkout.
So most of the features will not work.

Moreover using live webhooks add this url in IPNs
https://webhook.site/#!/a75d5efd-9be5-47f7-afc3-bd001b38033f

and give a try.

Please use latest version of 2checkout and use latest rest APIs.